# MySQL Query Function Seems to Prevent PHP Variable from Being Used in Table Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, variables

I have a custom `query()` function as shown here:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysqli_select_db($link, "database_table");

//executes a given sql query with the params and returns an array as result
function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;

//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);

//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

        $rows = array();

        if ($result!==true)
        while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($rows,$d);
        }

        //return json
        return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
        return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
}
```

I am then using the function in the following manner:

```
//check if username exists
$login = query("SELECT username FROM $userTable WHERE username='%s' limit 1", $user);
if (count($login['result'])>0) {
    errorJson('Username already exists');
}

//try to register the user
$result = query("INSERT INTO $userTable(username, password) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);
if (!$result['error']) {
//success
loginAfterRegistering($user, $pass);
} else {
//error
errorJson('Registration failed');
}
```

The variables that are passed to the active function above are:

`$pass=$_GET['password']`
`$user=$_GET[username]`
`$userTable="myTable_name";`

The only variable causing an issue is the `$userTable="myTable_name";`  If I place the name directly into the `query()` function like this:

```
$result = query("INSERT INTO myTable_name(username, password) VALUES('%s','%s')", $user, $pass);
```

Then there is no problem.  But I need to be able to place this as a PHP variable for other reasons.  I have tried `".$userTable."`, `"$userTable"` as well to name a few.  My guess is that I need to adjust the `query()` function to include the variable in some way as I have done with `$pass` and `$user`.  Is that right?  If so what is the cleanest way to do so?  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of just putting the query string into `query()`, try saving it to a variable first. Then you can echo out the query string and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What does mysql_error() output?  Have you tried wrapping the table name variable in tildas, e.g. `$userTable`

Comment: I think Dave meant backticks(``) and not tildas(~)

Comment: I have tried backticks... not working either.  the output is `{"error":"Registration failed"}`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn can you provide a code snippet or link to better help me understand your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I knew that there was a simple solution.  I found that the problem had to do with where the variable was being defined.  I had to move the variable definition within the function.  The variable was then picked up and is now functioning properly.

This query syntax ended up working out:

`$login = query("SELECT username FROM $userTable WHERE username='%s' limit 1", $user);`

Thanks for all the assistance from those who commented.